# SSO Authentication/Active Directory/weblogic/apache proxy issues

Tags: java, apache, single-sign-on

I have been asked to implement seamless SSO authentication against active directory for a weblogic web based application.
After loads of testing and experimentation I have managed to get all the chain working as required. 
Users logging in from a windows managed PC and using IE can seamlessly login to the web application.

After that, an apache was configured and installed between the web browser and weblogic in order to perform HTTPS-->HTTP termination. Once this was done the browser stopped performing seamless login - though basic authentication did work;

Investigating further, I noticed that the Authorization header was not forwarded across to weblogic which justifies why the authentication does not take place.
Note that the apache server I am using is 2.2.

Does anybody know if apache explicitly removes the Authorization header? I have also tried increasing the request maximum size to 30KB in case that was the problem

Thank you

Comment: Did you enabled `libapache-mod-auth-kerb` module ? And i have done Apache SSO using HTTP.keytab earlier, if you want me to post that doc i can.

Comment: thank you or your response. However my problem is this. I have already setup everything to work seamlessly between browser->weblogic->webapp. However, I need an apache in between in order to do HTTPS-->HTTP conversion. Whenever I hit directly weblogic everything works fine, however when I go through a apache BASIC authentication pop-up shows up. It seems that the Authorization header is not passed accross

Answer (score 0):

- We need to install the following package. 
           `apt-get install libapache-mod-auth-kerb`
- First we have copy the `HTTP.keytab` (which is generated at "Active Directory") to `etc/krb5.keytab` like as below.
           `cp /root/HTTP.keytab /etc/krb5.keytab`
- Next we will have to give proper permissions.
            `chown www-data:www-data /etc/krb5.keytab`
            `chmod 400 /etc/krb5.keytab`
- Next we go to Apache virtual hosts path
            `vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

Add one directory as like below

```
`<Directory />
          AuthName "Kerberos Login"
          AuthType Kerberos
          Krb5Keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
          KrbServiceName HTTP
          KrbAuthRealm YOURDOMAIN.LOCAL   //It is  Domain name of your server 
          KrbMethodNegotiate on
          KrbSaveCredentials on
          KrbVerifyKDC on
          Require valid-user
   </Directory>`
```

[image]

- Restart Apache web server
       `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
- Next go to browser of Active Directory client machine and hit the web server with FQDN of apache server. It will not ask you the password to open that website.

[image]

NOTE:

For explorer browser we need set `automatic logon with  user name and password` at `security` tab

`user authentication` -> `logon` ->  `automatic logon with  user name and password`

[image]

If you found any difficulties please update me.

Comment: Thank you for the through walkthrough, however the intended solution is to have weblogic to do the actual authentication. I have everything working when apache is not in the middle. Please see my comment above